# Errors on Attempting to Install 32-bit Chrome in 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, 64-bit, 32-bit, ubuntu-11.10

I'm running into issues while attempting to install 32-bit Google Chrome on Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit. I have my reasons for doing so, though they're rather complex. I'd like to know how to resolve the issues that I'm running into.

So far, I've downloaded the 32-bit .deb package from http://www.google.com/chrome/index.html#eula, then attempted to install it using the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

Upon running that, I'm getting the following output:

```
Selecting previously deselected package google-chrome-stable:i386.
(Reading database ... 159727 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking google-chrome-stable:i386 (from google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:i386:
 google-chrome-stable:i386 depends on libbz2-1.0.
 google-chrome-stable:i386 depends on libgconf2-4 (>= 2.27.0).
 google-chrome-stable:i386 depends on lsb-base (>= 3.2).
 google-chrome-stable:i386 depends on xdg-utils (>= 1.0.2).
dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable:i386
```

I've double-checked, and libbz2-1.0, libgconf2-4, lsb-base, and xdg-utils are all already installed. In my attempts to search on Google to try to resolve the issue, I've also installed ia32-libs.

Any other ideas? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome is looking for the 32-bit versions of libraries, which are not available in the repositories you have configured. Unfortunately, there is not really a good solution to this, since you will need to have two different versions of many libraries installed. For now, you can try just using the ia32-libs package as discussed [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/534). Things to look in to are [MultiArch](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchSpec), which is a new Ubuntu feature that appears to be mostly implemented. A little discussion of this issue can be found [here](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/2993/).

Edit: as of 2012, MultiArch support in Ubuntu is very good. Users will typically not encounter this type of error any more.